# Eigenvalues of matrix sums

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Under what conditions are the eigenvalues of $A+B$ equal to the eigenvalues of $A$ plus the eigenvalues of $B$, where $A,B$ are square matrices?

From searching, it seems that the condition is that $AB=BA$.  If that is indeed the case, why?

Comment: The trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues, and certainly the trace of $A + B$ equals the trace of $A$ plus the trace of $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, what do you mean by "the eigenvalues of $A$ plus the eigenvalues of $B$"?  What is true (under the condition $AB = BA$) is that each eigenvalue of $A+B$ is the sum of an eigenvalue of $A$ and an eigenvalue of $B$.  It is
not true in general that each sum of an eigenvalue of $A$ and an eigenvalue of $B$ is an eigenvalue of $A+B$.

If $A$ and $B$ commute, the generalized eigenspaces of $A$ are invariant under $B$, and you can use this to simultaneously put $A$ and $B$ in Jordan canonical form, i.e. get an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1} A P$ and $P^{-1} B P$ are in
 Jordan canonical form.  The sum of these is an upper triangular matrix similar to $A+B$, so its eigenvalues are its diagonal entries, and each of these is the sum of 
an eigenvalue of $A$ and an eigenvalue of $B$.

Comment: ok, thanks, i think this answers my questions.

Comment: @ Robert Israel . Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$; clearly $AB=BA$; yet, we cannot simultaneously put $A$ and $B$ in Jordan canonical form (otherwise $A=B$).

Comment: @ Robert Israel . There exist instances of commutative matrices  s.t. the associated triangular matrices $A',B'$ can neither one nor the other being written into Jordan form. Yet, we can put at least one matrix $A',B'$ into Weyr form.