# Relation between the Eigen values of the matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose given matrices $A$ and $B$. And we find it's Eigen values. Can we say anything about eigen values of $A+B$ and $AB$? Can there be possibility that Eigen values of $A+B$ is same as that of Eigen values of $A +$ Eigen values of $B$? Same for the $AB$. If so, what must be the restrictions on the matrix so as to happen as above?

Comment: Can it happen?  Of course.  Consider the $1\times 1$ matrices which act the same as regular numbers.

Comment: Can I get something more in general? Like for what type of matrices this can happen?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1394704/265466 for a start.

Comment: Consider the eigendecomposition of both $A = U\Sigma_AU'$ and $B = V\Sigma_BV'$. If these matrices have the same eigenvectors $U = V$, then for $A+B$, we have $\Sigma = \Sigma_A + \Sigma_B.$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202103/does-common-eigenvectors-between-two-matrices-a-b-implies-some-property-for-the